# How to wire up an EventHandler on a Winforms Application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application and I want to start a countdown timer.

I created an `EventHandler` under the partial class:

```
event EventHandler startTimer;
```

And I wrote a function:

```
public void startTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        timer.Start();
    });
}
```

How can I register this to the `EventHandler` and where do I wire it up in my form?

Comment: Where does `timer` come from in your `startTimerEve` method? (And why does it have such a strange name?) Also, your even isn't public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to choose an event that will trigger your handler. Let’s say you have a button, and you want to handle its click event. You could write:

```
myButton.Click += new EventHandler(StartWhatEver);
```

Then you would have your `StartWhatEver` that does what you want.

```
private void StartWhatEver(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Note: If you are working in VS2010, you can type `myButton.Click +=` (with space) then double tap the 'Tab' key and this will create your handler for you automatically including the triggered method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're missing `new` in your first code snip and it isn't actually necessary to have `new EventHandler`. `myButton.Click += SomeAmazingMethod` should work as long as `SomeAmazingMethod` has the correct signature.

Comment: Cheers for that. I know that you can just use `+=` but I prefer to be explicit, especially when discribing the methodology to someone that seems relitavely new to these features. All the best.

Comment: If you accept some of the answers that users have helped you out with before you will be more likely to have people help you in the future. It will also increase your Rep! :]

Comment: accept some of the answers by press on the V sign and then it's become green ?

Answer (score 2):

To tie the event to the handler:

```
startTimer += startTimerEvent;
```

But I'm not really sure there isn't a better way to go about solving your general problem. If you could describe further what you're after, perhaps we could suggest a better way.